# extreme lag after having .wav, .au sound in my game?

Tags: java, audio, user-interface

i tried to search up online there are very limited resources. in the action Performed Method:

```
actionPerformed(){
---------------
new Sound();}
```

and in Sound class

```
 public Sound(){
   try {
    String filePath="path\\file.wav";
    File path= new File(filePath);
    AudioInputStream stream;
    AudioFormat format;
    DataLine.Info info;
    Clip clip;

    stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path);
    format = stream.getFormat();//becomes formatted
    info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);// info
    clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);// casting for clip
    clip.open(stream); // clip opens stream with path
    clip.start();
}
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("errors");
    }
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Javadoc of the [`.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start%28%29) method:

> Allows a line to engage in data I/O. If invoked on a line that is
>   already running, this method does nothing. Unless the data in the
>   buffer has been flushed, the line resumes I/O starting with the first
>   frame that was unprocessed at the time the line was stopped. When
>   audio capture or playback starts, a START event is generated.

There is no mention of the audio being played in an asynchronous manner. This means that your sound will be tackled by the thread which calls the `start` method, which since you are calling it in your event handler, will eventually mean that your `Event Dispatching Thread` is taking care of playing audio.

This thread is also responsible for drawing stuff on screen, so any other thing that runs on it, audio in your case, will have a negative effect on your rendering.

You could use some code like below (taken from [here](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml)) to make your audio be played on a separate thread. This should cater for your lagging problems.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl; 
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 

public class AePlayWave extends Thread { 

    private String filename;

    private Position curPosition;

    private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; // 128Kb 

    enum Position { 
        LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
    };

    public AePlayWave(String wavfile) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
    } 

    public AePlayWave(String wavfile, Position p) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = p;
    } 

    public void run() { 

        File soundFile = new File(filename);
        if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
            System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + filename);
            return;
        } 

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try { 
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine auline = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try { 
            auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            auline.open(format);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                    .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
                pan.setValue(1.0f);
            else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
                pan.setValue(-1.0f);
        } 

        auline.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

        try { 
            while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                    auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally { 
            auline.drain();
            auline.close();
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: @Bango: Glad this helps. When dealing with UI, it is usually good practice to spawn off threads for any other task you might need so that you do not keep thte EDT busy :).

Comment: @Bango: That should mean that you are now playing your audio on your main thread ;).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the Lightweight Java Game Library's OpenAL bindings.

It worked very nicely for me when I had to write a game with a large number of sound files.

Other than that, Clips are named Clips for a reason; they're supposed to be very brief and very small, as they're loaded instead of streamed in real-time.

LWJGL:
http://www.lwjgl.org/