# Sound loading working in ubuntu but not working in windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, audio

I have written a method in java to play a sound. It works fine on my ubuntu laptop but doesnt work on windows. There is no error but i think it might be bypassing the drain method on windows for some reason.

```
public static void runOnce(final String location) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                File audioFile = new File(Game.gameFolder + "/sounds/" + location);
                final AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

                AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

                final Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

                audioClip.open(audioStream);
                audioClip.start();
                audioClip.drain();
                try {
                    audioClip.close();
                    audioStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("heyeyeyeyye");
                }
                System.out.println("sound method ran");
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }).start();
}
```

thanks -Tyler

EDIT:
i remember actually it worked on windows before i used drain but after a certain amount of time it wouldnt load anymore so i switched to drain

Comment: Not just a problem with the forward slashes in the path?

Comment: it actually plays the sound once every few minutes so it reads it for sure. also it prints "sound method ran" the amount of times it should/ the same amount of times as on ubuntu

Comment: @sje397 forward slashes will be translated by the JVM on windows.

Comment: Shouldn't you wait for the whole clip to be played before closing? What if you play an hour long clip

Comment: the whole clip does play... the drain waits until done thats why i have it in a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and that you `join()` the Thread you start and *never* swallow the message from your `Exception`. Something like,

```
public static void runOnce(final String location) {
    File audioFile = new File(Game.gameFolder + "/sounds/" + location);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try (AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem
                    .getAudioInputStream(audioFile);) {
                AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
                try (Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);) {
                    audioClip.open(audioStream);
                    audioClip.start();
                    audioClip.drain();
                }
                System.out.println("heyeyeyeyye");
                System.out.println("sound method ran");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: i just found a class that implements thread. it works on my computer (ubuntu) so when i can use my moms again i will test it on there. i got the class from the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009542/extreme-lag-after-having-wav-au-sound-in-my-game?rq=1) if you want to see it.

Comment: yep theres worked. yours probably would have too but theres seems like i can do more with it too anyways